How can I test every derived class for the same behavior?
For a piece of C++ software that requires certification, I'm required to prove that all the classes that are derived of a base class also satisfy the requirements for that base class.
I wonder how I can accomplish that without copying tests? I'm currently working with Google Test, but if other frameworks make this easier I'd be interested in hearing about them.

GoogleTests offers Typed Tests for this use case.

Suppose you have multiple implementations of the same interface and want to make sure that all of them satisfy some common requirements. [...] Typed tests allow you to repeat the same test logic over a list of types. You only need to write the test logic once, although you must know the type list when writing typed tests.

The process is described in detail in the link provided above.
